# I don't understand why this isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write some node.js and for some reason it's telling me this "'}' expected."
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 console.log(req);
  console.log(req.url);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');



   fs.readFile('./views/index.html', (err, data) => {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.end();
   }

     res.end(data);
});
```

Comment: Well `fs.readFile(` never seems to end...

Comment: As per [ask], please write descriptive question. A lot of people post about code problems. Imagine if everyone wrote "I don't understand why this isn't working" - we'd have no insight into any of the questions from looking at the title alone! Write something like "Why am I getting a '}' expected error?" so we have some indication of your question content.

Comment: If you fix your indentation so that a closing `}` is at the right level, this will be really easy to spot.  Or paste your code into a linter and it will tell you what is wrong.  You shouldn't need to come here for matching brace problems.

Comment: @Llama Thanks, I'm new to Stack Overflow, so I guess I'll have to read the guidelines carefully

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the callback function of fs.readFile by `});`

Below is Fixed full script:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(req.url);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

  fs.readFile('./views/index.html', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end();
    }

    res.end(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following style is not that popular, but it makes this harder to miss:

```
const server = http.createServer(
    (req, res) => {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(req.url);

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

        fs.readFile(
            './views/index.html',
            (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.end();
                }
                res.end(data);
             }
        );
```

And you need:

```
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `})` at the end of the `fs.readFile` function.

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(req.url);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  fs.readFile('./views/index.html', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end();
    }
    res.end(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Didn't notice that